# How to get average and total with the program I am building

Tags: python, loops, validation, average

I need to write a program in Python that utilizes a loop to read a set of five values from user input and print the following: total, average, maximum, minimum and interest at 20%. I also need to validate the input values. I'm struggling to understand what I need to do to fix this. I will put what I have tried, but it's failing after successfully validating. What am I doing wrong? If I could figure out how to get the total then I could probably get the rest no problem. This is what I have so far:

```
Number = 0
InputValue = ""
Total = 0
Average = 0
Interest = 0.2
Maximum = 0
Minimum = 0

for i in range(5):
    while True:
        InputValue = input("Enter a number: ")
        if InputValue == "":
            print("ERROR: Number must be supplied.")
        else:
            if InputValue.isdigit() == False:
                print("ERROR: Number must be a number.")
            else:
                Number = int(InputValue)
                if Number < 0 or Number > 100:
                    print("ERROR: Number must be between 0 and 100.")
        else:
                    break
    print("Continue to the next value...")
total = sum(Number)
minimum = min(Number)
maximum = max(Number)
average = total / 5
interest = total + (total * interest)
print("Total: ", total)
print("Average: ", average)
print("Minimum: ", minimum)
print("Maximum: ", maximum)
print("20% Interest of All Numbers Included Plus the Total: ", interest)
```

These are the results and error that I receive after inputting the numbers:

Enter a number: 50
Continue to the next value...
Enter a number: 40
Continue to the next value...
Enter a number: 30
Continue to the next value...
Enter a number: 20
Continue to the next value...
Enter a number: 10
Continue to the next value...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\ITS 320\TEST 2.py", line 49, in 
total = sum(Number)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: `Number` is a single number. `sum` needs an _iterable_, such as a list.

Comment: every time you do `Number = int(InputValue)` you _replace_ the current value of `Number` with a new value. If you want to use `sum`/`min`/`max` you need to instead build up a list of all the valid numbers that were input.

Comment: You need to put each input into a list. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response for cleaner ways to get a valid input. Also, note that there are many very well respected conventions in Python, described in PEP 8. See especially the part about variable names: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Comment: all the variables at the top begin with capitals and the same variables at the bottom are lower case - so the variables are inconsistent (python variables are case sensitive).

Comment: you have two consecutive else statements, which will cause your program to not run.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of looping through `range` AND a `while` loop, just use the `while` loop alone, since we don't know how many times we need to loop.
2. The validation can happen with an `if/elif/else` pattern instead of nested if statements. I've unwound one of those levels in the code below.
3. The results should be collected into a `list` or some sort of collection. I've called this `numbers` in the code below
4. `interest = total + (total * interest)` doesn't make any sense as the variable `interest` is not set, I'm assuming `Interest` was meant instead.

```
    Number = 0
    InputValue = ""
    Total = 0
    Average = 0
    Interest = 0.2
    Maximum = 0
    Minimum = 0
    
    numbers=[]
    
    #iterate until we fill `numbers` list with 5 numbers
    while True:
        InputValue = input("Enter a number: ")
        if InputValue == "":
            print("ERROR: Number must be supplied.")
        elif InputValue.isdigit() == False:
            print("ERROR: Number must be a number.")
        else:
            Number = int(InputValue)
            if Number < 0 or Number > 100:
                print("ERROR: Number must be between 0 and 100.")
            else:
                numbers.append(Number)
    
        print(numbers) # just for visibility sake. This line isn't necessary.   
        if len(numbers) == 5:
            break
    
    total = sum(numbers)
    minimum = min(numbers)
    maximum = max(numbers)
    average = total / 5
    interest = total + (total * Interest) 
    print("Total: ", total)
    print("Average: ", average)
    print("Minimum: ", minimum)
    print("Maximum: ", maximum)
    print("20% Interest of All Numbers Included Plus the Total: ", interest)
```